# Owncloud: Change system generated password of user oc_user

Tags: mysql, owncloud

I want to restore an owncloud installation by restoring the database and all web files.My problem is, that I used the root user for the mysql database and owncloud created another user called oc-michael (my account name is michael). Now I need the password of this user to be able to create a user with this password.

Or how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password of the MySQL user oc-michael is written in your /config/config.php at the 'dbpassword' variable.

Hint: Please note that this looks like a hash but its just a very long plaintext password which was auto-generated.